# Joomla 3 login failed - no error

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, joomla3.0

It all worked fine two days ago, but yesterday we could not log in to the front or back-end - the site requires a login for all users.

When we try to log in, the browser updates, but we stays on the login site.

There is no error message. There comes an error message by incorrect user or password.

We can also reset the password, but it does not help

It is a Joomla 3.2.7 site and PHP is 5.3.3

I've checked `plg_user_profile` in the database and cookie domain in `configuration.php`

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It must have been an error on the host server, because now it works again.